having issues when I am trying to run this command in my terminal "npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost"
this is the error  I received Error HH601: Script scripts/deploy.js doesn't exist. I am a total beginner and have tried many different options and none have worked
I was opening a hardhat node and that went fine but when I go to run the npx hardhat run scripts is when I encountered this error code
